# Easy navigation in excel within the same row with the aid of a hairline cross

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I have a Excel file (xls) with 20 sheets and like to navigate easily on the same row with the aid of a semi-transparent grey hairline cross. I'm a newbie in VBA and I've spend several hours searching a solution, unfortunately without success at now.

Let's say in B3 there is the number 7 written, in B4 the number 10:

a) if I click on an arbitrary cell, e.g. B3, I'd like to have a hairline cross over column B and row 3

b) if I mark with the mouse the fields B3 and B4, the hairline cross (initially at B3) should disappear, next when I go with the mouse coursor to the bottom right of the cell B4 and drag the "plus"-sign into the next cell B5 Excel automatically should paste the number 13 (difference of 3 added to number 10) in cell B5. The "formula-drag-and-drop" function should also work with formulas.
(With most Excel files /Add-Ins I've tried unfortunately this wasn't possible).

Does someone knows an easy and workable solution for aims a) and b)?

**EDIT:** Usability of other excel functions (e.g. undo and redo) should remain.

Comment: pls clarify (a), do u mean when you select cell G10, you want the entire row 10 highlighted and also entire column G highlighted ?

Comment: Question is not very clear - you start with the cross over G10, then "mark up" (what does that mean) B3 and B4, then state the cross was initially at B3. Wasn't it at G10?   Bottom right of what? Drag and drop what?  Where does the number 13 come from - where was it originally?  What is the *purpose* of the cross ?  What does it help with ?

Comment: Thank's a lot for your comments! I've edited my unclear initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assembled a piece of VBA that should match your requirements.
Just past the code in ThisWorkbook, it will activate the hairline cross in all the sheets.
FYI, the hairline cross is created with a conditional format on the current row/column and updated when the selection changes.

Code to place in ThisWorkbook :

```
Private Const CROSS_BACKGROUND_COLOR = &HE0E0EA
Private Const CROSS_BORDER_COLOR = &HE0E0E0
Private Const CROSS_PATTERN = xlPatternGray50
Private Const CELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR = &HFFFFFF

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
  Dim cdt As FormatCondition, cdtCross As FormatCondition, cdtCell As FormatCondition

  ' get the conditional formats for the sheet
  For Each cdt In Cells.FormatConditions
    If cdt.type = xlExpression Then
      If cdt.Formula1 = "=-1" Then
        Set cdtCell = cdt
      ElseIf cdt.Formula1 = "=-2" Then
        Set cdtCross = cdt
      End If
    End If
  Next

  ' diplay the cross if one cell is selected and if a copy/paste is not occuring
  If target.Columns.count = 1 And target.Rows.count = 1 And Application.CutCopyMode = 0 Then
    If cdtCell Is Nothing Then
      ' create the cross with a format condition on the row and column
      With target.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=-1")
        .Interior.Color = CELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR
      End With
      With Union(target.EntireRow, target.EntireColumn) _
           .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=-2")
        .Interior.PatternColor = CROSS_BACKGROUND_COLOR
        .Interior.pattern = CROSS_PATTERN
        .Borders.Color = CROSS_BORDER_COLOR
      End With
    Else
      ' update the position of the cross
      cdtCell.ModifyAppliesToRange target
      cdtCross.ModifyAppliesToRange Union(target.EntireRow, target.EntireColumn)
    End If
  ElseIf Not cdtCell Is Nothing Then
    ' hide the cross at the bottom if the selection has more than one cell
    If cdtCross.AppliesTo.Column - cdtCell.AppliesTo.Column <> 1 Then
      cdtCell.ModifyAppliesToRange Cells(sh.Rows.count, 1)
      cdtCross.ModifyAppliesToRange Cells(sh.Rows.count, 2)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Another solution less prone to issues would be to delete the format conditions for each section change. However it might be less performant.

EDIT2 : Added another version with support for a shortcut (Ctrl+Shif+8):

```
''
' Code to place in ThisWorkbook
''

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnKey "^+8", "ToggleCrossVisibility"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
  DeleteCross sh
  If target.Columns.count = 1 And target.Rows.count = 1 Then CreateCross target
End Sub

''
' Code to place in a new Module
''

Private Const CROSS_BACKGROUND_COLOR = &HD0D0DA
Private Const CROSS_BORDER_COLOR = &HE0E0E0
Private Const CROSS_PATTERN = xlPatternGray50
Private Const CELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR = &HFFFFFF

Private CrossDisabled As Boolean

Private Sub ToggleCrossVisibility()
  CrossDisabled = CrossDisabled Xor True
  DeleteCross ActiveSheet
  If Not CrossDisabled Then CreateCross ActiveCell
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteCross(ByVal target As Worksheet)
  ' delete the cross by deleting the conditions
  Static conditions(0 To 10) As FormatCondition
  Dim condition As FormatCondition, i&
  For Each condition In target.Cells.FormatConditions
    If condition.type = xlExpression Then
      If condition.Formula1 = "=-1" Then
        Set conditions(i) = condition
        i = i + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
  For i = 0 To i - 1
    conditions(i).Delete
  Next
End Sub

Public Sub CreateCross(ByVal target As Range)
  If CrossDisabled Then Exit Sub

  ' create the cross with a format condition on the row and column
  With target.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=-1")
    .Interior.color = CELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR
  End With
  With Union(target.EntireRow, target.EntireColumn) _
       .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=-1")
    .Interior.PatternColor = CROSS_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    .Interior.pattern = CROSS_PATTERN
    .Borders.color = CROSS_BORDER_COLOR
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution! Copy-Paste works. Adding new worksubsheet works. There is only one issue: I write "5" in A1, "7" in A2, mark A1 and A2, copy it, paste it on an arbitrary cell e.g. C4 and paste it again in an arbitrary cell e.g. E7: I get now two hairlines: one centred at C4 and one centred on E7. Can I do something to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like the paste is messing with the format condition so I disabled the cross when there is a copy/cut happening.

Comment: What is the asiest way to disable the cross? Do I need to delete the VBA Code or is it possible in an easier way (e.g. with a shortcut)?

Comment: You can install a shortcut with "Application.OnKey" in the "Workbook_Open" event procedure. The shortcut would call a procedure in a module that would delete or create all the conditions and toggle the state defined in a global variable. And if you wish to disable it in the code then add "Exit Sub" just after the deletion of the format conditions.

Comment: This sounds nice (it would be cool to toggle it in and out with the same shortcut e.g. Ctrl+Shift+8). Could you show me an example how to do it?

Comment: I updated the example. You'll have to reopen the workbook to activate the shortcut.

Comment: I get a runtimeerror '424' object required. If I click Debug I see the marked line: "DeleteCross ws"

Comment: I recognized the comments later, then I deleted my comment here in stackoverflow, but now I've got this runtimeerror issue.

Comment: The ws should be ActiveSheet. I will update it in the example.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the update! For me this seems to be the best solution I've ever seen :) Do you know a good online tutorial webpage or book to learn VBA for newbies in order to write VBA codes as you did in the code above?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any but it shouldn't be hard to find since there is nothing special about the code I wrote.

Comment: Don't matter. I need to have a look into tutorials for VBA newbies :) Again, thank you a lot for this nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer part (a), for part (b) since my solution to part (a) is not invasive to any cell's content, it will not affect your drag & drop, copy & paste and etc.

**1. Create a blank worksheet and name it "CTRL"**

[image]

**2. Open VBA editor (Alt+F11) and paste this code to `ThisWorkbook` module**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name <> "CTRL" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CTRL").Range("A1") = Target(1).Address
    End If
End Sub
```

**3. Create two name formula**

Click the Name Manager button and then click New.

[image]

First name formula is as follow:

[image]

Second name formula is as follow:

[image]

**4. Create a conditional formatting using a formula to determine which cells to format**

This, unfortunately, you need to create for each and every sheet.

The formatting rule is as follow:

[image]

This is the formula:

```
=OR(COLUMN(INDIRECT(ThisCellAddress))=COLUMN(INDIRECT(CrossAddress)),ROW(INDIRECT(ThisCellAddress))=ROW(INDIRECT(CrossAddress)))
```

The cell format you can choose 10% grey fill and white border on all sides.

And apply the rule to the entire worksheet, i.e. Applies to `=$1:$1048576`.

[image]

> **The outcome :**
>
> [image]

Comment: I like your idea. In my case it didn't worked. My Excel is installed in language german, therefore I translated all formulas into german (, into ; / or into oder / indirect into indirekt / column into spalte / row into reihe / address into adresse). In the VBA I didn't change anything. May be there is even an easier way with an Add-In? The color and the 10% filling is not so important.

Comment: This is a great idea, but couldn't you just use, "=OR(COLUMN()=COLUMN(INDIRECT(CrossAddress)),ROW()=ROW(INDIRECT(CrossAddress)))" and get rid of the whole "ThisCellAddress"?

Comment: @laminin. you are right, its easier with add-in. i've done this before but the invasive behaviour can cause cells that i manually formatted lost its colors and borders after i navigate away. hence i prefer my current non-invasive solution. but the problem is u'll have to create the conditional formatting for each and every worksheets. however you can write VBA to automate that, hence the whole procedure will be shorten to two simple steps. HTH.

Comment: @OpiesDad, thanks for the feedback! i didn't know that :)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Can you upload your worksheet? (    because it doesn't work in my excel) with the used formula: =ODER(ZEILE()=ZEILE(INDIREKT(CrossAddress));SPALTE()=SPALTE(INDIREKT(CrossAddress)))    )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this Cross Hair Highlight (CHH) for all your 20 sheets and each sheet retains the cross hair, you will need to place codes in each Worksheet object, and a Normal Module.

The CHH will be applied on the column and row of selected cell except itself. When more than 1 cells are selected, the CHH will be removed.

**Codes for each Worksheet Object that features CHH**:
[image: Sheet1 Code]

```
Option Explicit

Private oPrevRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    RangeSelectionChange Target, oPrevRange
End Sub
```

Create a new Module, say "**CrossHair**" and place below code (*revised to add borders on cells*):

```
Option Explicit

Private Const lColorCross As Long = 14277081 ' White with 15% darker: RGB(217,217,217)

Sub RangeSelectionChange(ByRef Target As Range, ByRef oPrevRange As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    With Target
        If .Count = 1 Then
            If Not oPrevRange Is Nothing Then
                ' Undo highlight on previous range
                If .Row <> oPrevRange.Row Then UndoCrossHairRow oPrevRange
                If .Column <> oPrevRange.Column Then UndoCrossHairCol oPrevRange
            End If
            Set oPrevRange = Target
            MakeCrossHair Target
        Else
            UndoCrossHair oPrevRange
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub MakeCrossHair(ByRef oRng As Range)
    With oRng
        With .EntireRow
            .Interior.Color = lColorCross
            With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ThemeColor = 1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End With
        With .EntireColumn
            .Interior.Color = lColorCross
            With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ThemeColor = 1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End With
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UndoCrossHair(ByRef oRng As Range)
    UndoCrossHairRow oRng
    UndoCrossHairCol oRng
End Sub

Private Sub UndoCrossHairRow(ByRef oRng As Range)
    oRng.EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    oRng.EntireRow.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
End Sub

Private Sub UndoCrossHairCol(ByRef oRng As Range)
    oRng.EntireColumn.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    oRng.EntireColumn.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End Sub
```

These interactions does not interfere normal Excel features, so second part of (b) is not an issue.

The only issue is if your data is already formatted nicely, this CHH with ruin it.

**Sample screenshots:**
Note some range (non Table ranges) has yellow filled background which got removed by CHH. It will be very hard to allow restoring them.
[image: F9 selected]
[image: C10 selected]
[image: D13 selected]

Comment: Hi PatricK: Thank you very much for your nice answer! a) May be there is even a way to define the code globally? I already defined initially the format of individual cells. After inserting the code I didn't recognized any error. b) Which examples of errors with misplaced formatting can happen? c) Is it possible instead of changing the number 14277081 in "Private Const lColorCross As Long = 14277081 ' White with 15% darker: RGB(217,217,217)" to insert a line for transparency of 50 %, that you can still see the gridlines?

Comment: This solution was just to change the background color for the whole row and column of the 1 selected cell. I cannot think of any other simpler method beside an add-in. If you prefer a semi-transparent rectangles above,below,left and right of the 1 selected cell, it can be tricky, but something to play with.

Answer (score 0):

put this in ThisWorkbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

With Target
    If .Count = 1 Then
        Sh.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        With ActiveCell
            .EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            .EntireColumn.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        End With            
    Else
            Sh.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            If .Count = 3 And .Columns.Count = 1 Then .Cells(3, 1) = 10 + (.Cells(2, 1) - .Cells(1, 1))
    End If        
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately the standard undo function is disabled.

Comment: I'm sorry: I meant the excel undo and redo button are no longer usable while the Add-In is activ.

Comment: you didn't mention undo usability in your Q, so I didn't care about it. furthermore it seems to me my A only addresses both part a) and b) of your Q. this is what poor specs bring in: waste of time...

Comment: I'm very sorry I wasn't able to satisfy you. I think your code helped me to better understand how a VBA code really looks like. For this help I'd like to say thank you for your effort. And I also think you're right. I mentioned the problem after I recognized it was one. There have been other very nice code samples as yours, so I needed to accept the answer which seemed to me the most useful for Excel users.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using some add-in like 
[rowliner](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rowliner.htm)?

Comment: Rowliner seems at first view a very nice tool. However you  need to disable the Add-In in order to use the undo function. This seems to me one of the major drawback of this Add-In.