# Selection Crosshair for Non-Adjacent Cell Selection

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:** I have a large Excel worksheet in which I created a "crosshair" for easy comparisons between data in the same row and column as the currently selected cell. Most "crosshair" navigation tricks I have seen use [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817040/easy-navigation-in-excel-within-the-same-row-with-the-aid-of-a-hairline-cross/), which would either delete or overwrite my existing conditional formatting. My work-around was to use a transparent line to highlight the row and column of the currently selected cell.

**Problem:** The code works for most selection sets, except for non-adjacent cell selections. For non-adjacent cells, it only highlights the first cell in the selection. *Ex:* If I select `F10` then select `H6`, I expect two crosshairs: one centered at `F10`, and another centered at `H6`. Instead, there is a single crosshair centered at `F10`.

[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to create a selection crosshair which will work for non-adjacent cell selections?

**Current Code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim On_Off As Boolean
    On_Off = True
    If On_Off = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Sht = ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Selection
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim Clr As Long
    Dim RWt As Double
    Dim CWt As Double
    Dim Trns As Double

    Clr = RGB(100, 20, 180)
    Trns = 0.85
    RWt = Rng.Height
    CWt = Rng.Width

    Debug.Print Rng.Address(False, False, xlA1)

    For Each Shp In Sht.Shapes
        If Shp.Name = "RowLine" Or Shp.Name = "ColLine" Then
            Shp.Delete
        End If
    Next Shp

    With Sht.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 0, _
        Rng.Top + Rng.Height / 2, 10000, Rng.Top + Rng.Height / 2)
        .Name = "RowLine"
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = Clr
        .Line.Transparency = Trns
        .Line.Weight = RWt
    End With

    With Sht.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, _
        Rng.Left + Rng.Width / 2, 0, Rng.Left + Rng.Width / 2, 10000)
        .Name = "ColLine"
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = Clr
        .Line.Transparency = Trns
        .Line.Weight = CWt
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

EDIT: added different colors for up to 3 distinct areas

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim On_Off As Boolean
    On_Off = True
    If On_Off = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range, a As Range, c As Range, i As Long
    Set Sht = ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Selection
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim Clrs
    Dim RWt As Double
    Dim CWt As Double
    Dim Trns As Double

    Clrs = Array(vbRed, vbYellow, vbGreen)
    Trns = 0.85

    For Each Shp In Sht.Shapes
        If Shp.Name Like "RowLine*" Or Shp.Name Like "ColLine*" Then
            Shp.Delete
        End If
    Next Shp

    For Each a In Rng.Areas
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print a.Address(False, False, xlA1)

        With Sht.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 0, _
            a.Top + a.Height / 2, 10000, a.Top + a.Height / 2)
            .Name = "RowLine" & i
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = Clrs(i Mod 3)
            .Line.Transparency = Trns
            .Line.Weight = a.Height
        End With

        With Sht.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, _
            a.Left + a.Width / 2, 0, a.Left + a.Width / 2, 10000)
            .Name = "ColLine" & i
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = Clrs(i Mod 3)
            .Line.Transparency = Trns
            .Line.Weight = a.Width
        End With

    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: this approach prevents you from selecting non-adjacent cells from the same row/column. Still, +1

Comment: Worked like a charm! And @FernandoJ.Rivera, you're right... I'm still looking for a work-around, but it hasn't been a major issue as of yet for my case.

Comment: Small change to get the exact behavior I was expecting: Replace `.Line.Weight = Rwt` and `.Line.Weight = Cwt` with `.Line.Weight = a.Height` and `.Line.Weight = a.Width`, respectively.

Comment: ++nice one :) FOr non adjacent cells, there is a different approach@E.Merckx

Comment: @SiddharthRout What would be a better approach for non-adjacent cells? I'm always interested in hearing alternative methods.

Comment: @E.Merckx: Before I confirm, Is [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ossir.png) how it should look like when you select `F10` then select `H6`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, I believe so. I'm only looking at the case where I have both cells selected. (i.e. click `F10`, hold ctrl, click `H6`).

Comment: yup that is what I meant.. @E.Merckx. Quick quesiton. Would you be selecting more than 2 cells?

Comment: @TimWilliams: I am sorry to hijack this

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, potentially.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - no problem.  The more the merrier.

Answer (score 5):

> The code works for most selection sets, except for non-adjacent cell selections. For non-adjacent cells, it only highlights the first cell in the selection. Ex: If I select F10 then select H6, I expect two crosshairs: one centered at F10, and another centered at H6

The approach you are currently following will not work when you have to select the `non-adjacent` cell in the same row as the shape will block the cell by superimposing itself.

**Alternative Approach**

The logic can be best explained by a question.

What happens when you record a macro and then select `Col F` and then `Row 10` and then `Col H` and `Row 6`?

[image]

This is exactly what you want to happen when you select `F10` and then select `H6` using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

If you look at the code the macro recorder created, you will see

```
Range("F:F,10:10,H:H,6:6").Select
```

And this is where the entire logic is based on.

**Code**

I have not done any error handling. I am sure you can take care of it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim addr As String

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range, CompleteSelection As Range, LastCell As Range
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim col As Long, rw As Long
    Dim MyAr

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub

    Set CompleteSelection = Nothing
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then addr = ""

    If InStr(1, Target.Address, ",") Then
        MyAr = Split(Target.Address, ",")
        sTemp = MyAr(UBound(MyAr))
        Set aCell = Range(sTemp)
    Else
        Set aCell = Target
    End If

    Set LastCell = aCell

    col = aCell.Column: rw = aCell.Row

    sTemp = Split(Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1) & ":" & _
               Split(Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1) & "," & _
               rw & ":" & rw

    If addr = "" Then
        addr = sTemp
    Else
        addr = addr & "," & sTemp
    End If

    Set CompleteSelection = Range(addr)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not CompleteSelection Is Nothing Then CompleteSelection.Select
    LastCell.Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach! Tim's approach is more suitable for my current application, but I will likely use this in the future. Is there a way to enable copy/cut with this method?

Comment: `Is there a way to enable copy/cut with this method?` I am sure that can be managed

Comment: Very nice, I wouldn't have thought to use the selection highlighting as markers. However, this only works with point selection (selecting single cells), it doesn't work when selecting adjacent ranges.

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera: Yes this is just a sample code. It does not handle ranges with more rows and columns. It can however be tweaked to handle those as well.